# how to improve website loading time improvement which approach is best?

Tags: performance, web, html, performance-testing, web-testing

today I was checking for the loading time of the website. I used webtestpage.org to see which resource takes how much time.

I have attached the spanshot for the result.
 [webpagetest image for homepage](http://www.webpagetest.org/result/140205_RX_DE5/1/details/)
[webpagetest image for perl editor](http://www.webpagetest.org/result/140205_JY_EJT/1/details/)

it takes much time to load so help me to improve my site performance

here is links which i cheked in webpagetest.org

[1st link](http://www.guru99.com/)
[2nd link](http://www.guru99.com/try-perl.html)

help me and give suggestions what i have do to minimize website loading time

Answer (score 1):

try below,

1. use gooogle pagespeed utility to check some level1 optimizations (it will tell you your heavy javascripts,minified version of them,heavy images,heavy css etc) probably then you can optimize it further
2. check server health (system resource utilization), if system configuration is not enough improve it
3. use profiler for complete performance insight of your application that will show you which methods/webservices etc are heavy and then decide how to optimize them.

Comment: there are different profilers available opersource as well as paid (they have different techniques to use them). but generally they are like you install agent of server, perform operations on server i.e. your desired workflow and later profiler agent will send data to profiler server with all details and profiler server after analysis will provide perf insights

Comment: see demo video here just a sample profiler, http://www.compuware.com/en_us/application-performance-management/products/application-monitoring/java-net-php.html

Answer (score 0):

Google pagespeed can help you.

Also a lot of time is consumed in data transfer, try to use tools like [OptimizeSuite](http://optimizesuite.net/) to reduce elements such images, js or css.