# Page load time issue

Tags: performance, time, load, orchardcms

Please help me in knowing answer for following question:

I'm struggling with page load time? Need to improve performance on page load time? How to do this with the website developed in Orchard CMS? Please describe results.

Look forward to hearing on this.

Thanks

Comment: find what is taking time. try browser plugins possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21576517/how-to-improve-website-loading-time-improvement-which-approach-is-best/21577038#21577038

Comment: I could have answered but I think above should help. if you have anything specific then please mention it in question and I'll try to answer.

Comment: Profile it to find where the bottlenecks are. The question is way too broad.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not specifying which specific "page" within Orchard you are looking at it is hard to provide any real answers.  However, to add to the comment above I would suggest that you look at installing the MiniProfiler module, which can be found in the Module Gallery page of your Orchard Site.

When enabled this tool will show you how long any page is taking to load - with details on how long each specific shape/template is taking to load ( as opposed to the page itself) as well as underlying SQL queries.

Bertrand has a simple blog post that talks about how to make this tool work for admin pages, which helped me greatly in trying to improve load times for content authoring

https://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/making-miniprofiler-work-in-the-orchard-dashboard